# How to Apply my VBA code to whole cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub level()
x = Range("f1").Value
Select Case x

Case 0 To 4.4
Range("b1").Value = 10
Case 4.4 To 9.4
Range("b1").Value = " B"
Case Else
Range("b1").Value = "false"
End Select
End Sub
```

it is Just for a cell 'F1'.I want to have these code for F1 to F365.
i'd tried some `FOR` loops but not have desire result
!!??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub level()

    For Each x In Range("F1:F365")
        'x.Offset(0, -4) gets B1 for F1, B2 for F2 and so on..'
        With x.Offset(0, -4)
            Select Case x
                Case 0 To 4.4
                    .Value = 10
                Case 4.4 To 9.4
                    .Value = " B"
                Case Else
                    .Value = "false"
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: yes it is working.thanks for your immediate reply (less than 5 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `IF` test and then convert to values, or do it in a single shot as below

```
 Sub Quick()
[f1:f65] = Application.Evaluate("=IF(B1:B365>0,IF(B1:B365>4.4,IF(B1:B365>9.4,""false"",""B""),""10""),""false"")")
 End Sub
```